# How can I restrict access, by IP, to the `wp-admin` folder/Dashboard?

Tags: htaccess

I would like to prevent all IP addresses from accessing the WordPress Dashboard; with the exception of 1 IP address.

I have created a `.htaccess` file and placed this within the `wp-admin` folder.  Said file has the following code:

```
ErrorDocument 401 /example.com/index.php?error=404
ErrorDocument 403 /example.com/index.php?error=404

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-login\.php(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-admin$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=403,L]
</IfModule>
```

Obviously, replacing `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` with the desired IP address and `example.com` with the correct domain name.

The problem is, it seems the `.htaccess`, within the root folder, is preventing this `.htaccess` file from working.  The only way I can seem to get this `.htaccess` file to work, is to remove the root level variant; something which would cause other issues.

How can I resolve this issue?

**Update:**

I have figured out what is causing the issue.  It is the following entry, within the Root level `.htaccess` file:

```
# Restrict following Spam IP Addresses:
<Files *>
order allow,deny
allow from all
deny from xx.xxx.x.xx
deny from xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
deny from xx.xxx.x.x
</Files>
```

More specifically, the `allow from all` entry.  If I remove the above entry, in its entirety, then I am able to restrict access to the `wp-admin.php` file.  The problem then, is that I am unable to restrict site wide access by specific IP address.  It is as if `allow from all` overrides everything else.

Comment: Strange, it should be the other way round: the .htaccess file in the wp-admin folder would normally override the .htaccess file in the root? What version of Apache are you on?

Comment: I thought that too but it does not seem the case.  Could it be that I may be missing something; before, after or within the code?  The Apache version is:  2.2.15  I can see that the latest version is:  2.4.33.  Could this really be a factor?

Comment: Please include the contents of the root `.htaccess` file - maybe there is a conflict that creates this _illusion_? Different modules are independent and inherit in different ways. On Apache 2.2 mod_rewrite inheritance is very limited, so these mod_rewrite directives in the subdirectory `.htaccess` file can only override the parent mod_rewrite directives. However, if you have other directives from mod_authz_host (for example) in the parent `.htaccess` file that grant access then these will take priority (it doesn't prevent the subdirectory `.htaccess` file from "working", they simply "win").

Comment: " before, after or within the code?" - which "code" are you referring to?

Comment: @MrWhite ... Thanks for your time, with this issue. I have modified the question, to include my recent findings.

Comment: restricting access by IP is a security theater that should be avoided. you are more likely to break things than you realize and your security will not be improved at all.

Comment: @MarkKaplun What?! Please explain or provide a reference.

Comment: @MrWhite first thing that will die that way is anything which is front end ajax. As for security, most breaches happen via direct access to plugin code, something that is not handled with that. xml-rpc obviously still exposed and so is the rest api.

Comment: if you want to restrict some "admin" access based on IP address, the only robust way is to check it when capabilities are being checked

Comment: @MarkKaplun ... Thank you for that insight. I have not yet experienced any Ajax issues. Are you aware of any resource on checking IPs  when capabilities are checked? Not 100% sure on that matter.

Comment: @MarkKaplun There's no reason why a "front end ajax" request should "die" - it's from the same IP address as the initial (allowed) request.

Comment: @MrWhite Imagine a "load more posts" kind of functionality in a theme, how will that work when you effectively disabled ajax for every one not on that ip

Comment: @MrWhite For you alone they won't stop working. You need to check this from another IP address than the allowed one

Comment: @MarkKaplun / kero - Ah, I see... `admin-ajax.php` (part of the WP AJAX API) is located in the `/wp-admin` subdirectory. So, if you're using the WP AJAX API then it will indeed be blocked if this subdirectory is blocked! (But otherwise, _vanilla_ (non-WP) "AJAX requests" shouldn't be blocked?!) (_Aside:_ Why is `admin-ajax.php` located in the `/wp-admin` subdirectory? Why is it prefixed with `admin-`? When it's not related to _admin_ only tasks?)

Comment: @MrWhite the reason is history, it was designed first to be used for admin related ajax and expanded only after that. The right way to do ajax now days is to create a json route, but even core have problems with implementing this kind of migration (I guess that mostly because there is nothing sexy about doing it, so less people interested in it)

Comment: ... and once core will migrate to using json end points, blocking `wp-admin` will not be enough as at least some of the admin will be done by AJAX on the json end point which is outside of wp-admin